# Build error: unknown file type .pxd - pycodec2

Tags: python, c, build

I'm working on a project that uses the python library Pycodec2 in order for the
library to work it needs codec2 installed. The issue I'm having is when I try to build/install the library I'm getting this error below.

pacman -S codec2

pip install pycodec2 / same issue if I use python setup.py install

```
Collecting pycodec2
  Using cached pycodec2-2.1.0.tar.gz (62 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycodec2
  Building wheel for pycodec2 (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pycodec2 (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      building 'pycodec2' extension
      error: unknown file type '.pxd' (from 'pycodec2/codec2.pxd')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycodec2
Failed to build pycodec2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycodec2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

```
          <------- Some Guy on GitHub has the same issue ------->
https://github.com/gregorias/pycodec2
```

pip installed the following
"numpy",
"setuptools",
"wheel",
"Cython"

I know codec2 is installed

```
pacman -Ql codec2
codec2 /usr/
codec2 /usr/bin/
codec2 /usr/bin/c2ch
codec2 /usr/bin/c2dec
codec2 /usr/bin/c2demo
codec2 /usr/bin/c2enc
codec2 /usr/bin/c2sim
codec2 /usr/bin/cohpsk_demod
codec2 /usr/bin/cohpsk_get_test_bits
codec2 /usr/bin/cohpsk_mod
codec2 /usr/bin/cohpsk_put_test_bits
codec2 /usr/bin/fdmdv_demod
codec2 /usr/bin/fdmdv_get_test_bits
codec2 /usr/bin/fdmdv_mod
codec2 /usr/bin/fdmdv_put_test_bits
codec2 /usr/bin/freedv_rx
codec2 /usr/bin/freedv_tx
codec2 /usr/bin/fsk_demod
codec2 /usr/bin/fsk_get_test_bits
codec2 /usr/bin/fsk_mod
codec2 /usr/bin/fsk_mod_ext_vco
codec2 /usr/bin/fsk_put_test_bits
codec2 /usr/bin/ldpc_dec
codec2 /usr/bin/ldpc_enc
codec2 /usr/bin/ldpc_noise
codec2 /usr/bin/ofdm_demod
codec2 /usr/bin/ofdm_get_test_bits
codec2 /usr/bin/ofdm_mod
codec2 /usr/bin/ofdm_put_test_bits
codec2 /usr/include/
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/codec2.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/codec2_cohpsk.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/codec2_fdmdv.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/codec2_fifo.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/codec2_fm.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/codec2_math.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/codec2_ofdm.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/comp.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/freedv_api.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/fsk.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/modem_stats.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/reliable_text.h
codec2 /usr/include/codec2/version.h
codec2 /usr/lib/
codec2 /usr/lib/cmake/
codec2 /usr/lib/cmake/codec2/
codec2 /usr/lib/cmake/codec2/codec2-config-none.cmake
codec2 /usr/lib/cmake/codec2/codec2-config.cmake
codec2 /usr/lib/libcodec2.so
codec2 /usr/lib/libcodec2.so.1.1
codec2 /usr/lib/pkgconfig/
codec2 /usr/lib/pkgconfig/codec2.pc
```

ran this `cythonize -i codec2.pxd` to see what the setup.py was doing
and go the same error bellow

> error: unknown file type '.pxd' (from
> '/home/XX0XX/dev/pycodec2-main/pycodec2/codec2.pxd')

Some help finding out why I'm getting this error would be great
error: unknown file type '.pxd' (from 'pycodec2/codec2.pxd')

Also, I tried installing the same library on Alma Linux got the same error.

THANKS

Comment: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html

Well I wonder if this is a cythonize version issue

Comment: looks like the setup.py should be only cythonize pycodec2.pyx not the .pdx
Testing ......

Comment: OK looks like removing line 10 of the setup.py --> "pycodec2/codec2.pxd"
might fix the issue